# Javascript code summing primes is looping weirdly

Tags: javascript, for-loop, primes

I have the following code where I'm trying to sum all the primes up to 10.

I'm not trying to find the most efficient code or the correct code for this question but I'm having difficulty grasping how the for-loop is acting. I specifically mean when `i = 7`.

Since I have 2 nested for-loops, for some reason the `i = 7` outer loop is looping more than once, what I mean is that the inner loop is seemingly reaching its termination condition `j < k` where at that moment `j = 2` and `k = 2` yet it appears to insist on continuing to loop.

Here's the code:

```
var array = [2];
var total = 0; 
function isPrime(i, j) {
    if ( i%array[j] === 0 ) {
        console.log("Not P Check: i was " + i + ", j was " + j + " and k was " + k);
        console.log(i + " is not a prime");
        k = j;
    }
    else if ((j + 1) === array.length) {
        console.log(i + " is a prime");
        total += i;
        console.log("total so far is " + total);
        array.push(i);
        console.log(array);
        k = j;
        console.log("is P Check: i was " + i + ", j was " + j + " and k was " + k);
    }
    else {
        j++;
        console.log("Check " + (j + 1) + ": i is " + i + ", j is " + j + " and k is " + k);
        isPrime(i,j);
    }
}

for(var i = 3; i <=10; i++) {
   var k = array.length;
   for(var j = 0; j < k; j++) {
       console.log("Check 1: i is " + i + ", j is " + j + " and k is " + k);
       isPrime(i, j);
   }
}

console.log(total);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: How did you determine it loops more than once?

Comment: It looks like your inner loop is unnecessary, your isPrime function is already doing that work?

Comment: @jack I just added a console.log  line inside the loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the inner loop is unnecessary in your solution. Your recursive function is already doing the work of the inner loop. What happens in the inner loop is that some numbers are all repeated more than necessary.

Dygestor's solution is one approach. The other approach is simpler

```
for(var i = 3; i <= 10; i++) {
  isPrime(i, 0);
}
```

The logs for your method:

```
Check 1: i is 3, j is 0 and k is 1
3 is a prime
total so far is 3
[2, 3]
is P Check: i was 3, j was 0 and k was 0
Check 1: i is 4, j is 0 and k is 2
Not P Check: i was 4, j was 0 and k was 2
4 is not a prime
Check 1: i is 5, j is 0 and k is 2
Check 2: i is 5, j is 1 and k is 2
5 is a prime
total so far is 8
[2, 3, 5]
is P Check: i was 5, j was 1 and k was 1
Check 1: i is 6, j is 0 and k is 3
Not P Check: i was 6, j was 0 and k was 3
6 is not a prime
Check 1: i is 7, j is 0 and k is 3
Check 2: i is 7, j is 1 and k is 3
Check 3: i is 7, j is 2 and k is 3
7 is a prime
total so far is 15
[2, 3, 5, 7]
is P Check: i was 7, j was 2 and k was 2
Check 1: i is 7, j is 1 and k is 2
Check 3: i is 7, j is 2 and k is 2
Check 4: i is 7, j is 3 and k is 2
Not P Check: i was 7, j was 3 and k was 2
7 is not a prime
Check 1: i is 7, j is 2 and k is 3
Check 4: i is 7, j is 3 and k is 3
Not P Check: i was 7, j was 3 and k was 3
7 is not a prime
Check 1: i is 8, j is 0 and k is 4
Not P Check: i was 8, j was 0 and k was 4
8 is not a prime
Check 1: i is 9, j is 0 and k is 4
Check 2: i is 9, j is 1 and k is 4
Not P Check: i was 9, j was 1 and k was 4
9 is not a prime
Check 1: i is 10, j is 0 and k is 4
Not P Check: i was 10, j was 0 and k was 4
10 is not a prime
15
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

The logs removing the inner loop (bear in mind this is missing the `console.log` inside the inner loop as well):

```
3 is a prime
total so far is 3
[2, 3]
is P Check: i was 3, j was 0 and k was 0
Not P Check: i was 4, j was 0 and k was 0
4 is not a prime
Check 2: i is 5, j is 1 and k is 0
5 is a prime
total so far is 8
[2, 3, 5]
is P Check: i was 5, j was 1 and k was 1
Not P Check: i was 6, j was 0 and k was 1
6 is not a prime
Check 2: i is 7, j is 1 and k is 0
Check 3: i is 7, j is 2 and k is 0
7 is a prime
total so far is 15
[2, 3, 5, 7]
is P Check: i was 7, j was 2 and k was 2
Not P Check: i was 8, j was 0 and k was 2
8 is not a prime
Check 2: i is 9, j is 1 and k is 0
Not P Check: i was 9, j was 1 and k was 0
9 is not a prime
Not P Check: i was 10, j was 0 and k was 1
10 is not a prime
15
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Also the `k` variable is unnecessary in the new solution. `j` will increment until it reaches the end of the primes array or until the target number is divisible, whichever is sooner.

If you want to use the inner loop solution, you will need to remove your recursive function and do something like:

```
var primes = [2];
var sum = 0;

// Start looping
for(var i = 3; i <= 10; ++i) {
  var prime = true; // Prime until proven innocent
  for(var j = 0; j < primes.length; ++j) { // Length stays same until later
    if(i % arr[j] === 0) { // The meat of your isPrime function: divisible?
      prime = false;
      break; // Stop the loop early: number is not prime!
    }
  }
  if(prime) { // We have a prime!
    primes.push(i); // Add it to our list of primes
    sum += i; // Add the prime to the sum
  }
}

// Log the result
console.log("The sum of primes up to 10 (inclusive)", sum);
console.log("These primes were", primes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/yLby9/ and edited a few lines. Basically, I changed isPrime to return a boolean value and told that loop to break once it finds a prime number. In your version, when it got to 7, 7 was pushed into array (array.length increased). Now when we already found out, that 7 is a prime number, we want to break out of our inner loop and continue with different i.

```
var array = [2];
var total = 0; 
function isPrime(i, j) {
    if ( i%array[j] === 0 ) {
        console.log("Not P Check: i was " + i + ", j was " + j + " and k was " + k);
        console.log(i + " is not a prime");
        k = j;
        return false;
    }
    else if ((j + 1) === array.length) {
        console.log(i + " is a prime");
        total += i;
        console.log("total so far is " + total);
        array.push(i);
        console.log(array);
        k = j;
        return true;
        console.log("is P Check: i was " + i + ", j was " + j + " and k was " + k);
    }
    else {
        j++;
        console.log("Check " + (j + 1) + ": i is " + i + ", j is " + j + " and k is " + k);
        return isPrime(i,j);
    }
}

for(var i = 3; i <=10; i++) {
   var k = array.length;
   for(var j = 0; j < k; j++) {
       console.log("Check 1: i is " + i + ", j is " + j + " and k is " + k);
       if (isPrime(i, j)) break;
   }
}

console.log(total);
console.log(array);
```